# How to correctly implement f1-score as scoring metric in grid search with keras?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, metrics

I want to tune my keras neural net using GridSearchCV with respect to the metric f1-score since I have high imbalance in dataset. It is a binary classification problem. Here is what I have tried

```
def f1(y_true, y_pred):
   y_pred = K.round(y_pred)
   tp = K.sum(K.cast(y_true*y_pred, 'float'), axis=0)
   # tn = K.sum(K.cast((1-y_true)*(1-y_pred), 'float'), axis=0)
   fp = K.sum(K.cast((1-y_true)*y_pred, 'float'), axis=0)
   fn = K.sum(K.cast(y_true*(1-y_pred), 'float'), axis=0)

   p = tp / (tp + fp + K.epsilon())
   r = tp / (tp + fn + K.epsilon())

   f1 = 2*p*r / (p+r+K.epsilon())
   f1 = tf.where(tf.is_nan(f1), tf.zeros_like(f1), f1)
   return K.mean(f1)

def create_model():
   model = Sequential()
   model.add(Dense(899, activation = 'relu', input_dim = 899))
   model.add(Dense(100, activation = 'relu'))
   model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
   model.compile(optimizer= 'adamax', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = [f1])
   return model


param_grid = dict(batch_size = batch_size, epochs = epochs,class_weight = class_weight)
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = model, param_grid = param_grid, n_jobs =7, cv = 2, scoring = f1 )
```

But I get the error

```
**
score = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)
TypeError: f1() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
"""
**
```

so it looks like I need to create a scorer as well? How would one go on about doing that correctly?

UPDATE:

This seems to solve it, I think it works as intended

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer

f1_scorer = make_scorer(f1_score)
```

Which I then pass to the GridsearchCV function

```
grid = GridSearchCV(estimator = model, param_grid = param_grid, n_jobs =7, cv = 2, scoring = f1_scorer )
```

Comment: `score = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)` I don't see this line of code in your example. Did you run it standalone? What is a `scorer`? As an aside, I notice that you have a variable inside of the function `f1` called `f1`. You should probably come up with distinct names, to avoid confusion.

Comment: Hi, the score = scorer(...) is what I get in my error log. Such that Gridsearch is trying to calculate the score by passing 3 arguments. Thank you for the heads up!

Comment: The error as you've shown it isn't enough information for us to work from. Can you provide the full relevant traceback?

Comment: I think I solved it, see update

Comment: Although I did read this blogpost, which seems to say that it does not make sense to calculate F-score on each batch, but you should do it at the end of each epoch. Any idea if this is true? https://medium.com/@thongonary/how-to-compute-f1-score-for-each-epoch-in-keras-a1acd17715a2